# GetUpdate keeps sending updates endlessly

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram-api

i'm writing a Telegram bot without using any library but only using HTTP request. The problem is that i keep getting updates endlessly when i start long polling, here's my code:

```
public async Task StartPolling(string[] allowedUpdates = default!)
    {
        int messageOffset = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending GetUpdate with offset " + messageOffset);

            var updates = await GetUpdatesAsync(offset: messageOffset, timeout: Convert.ToInt32(s_httpClient.Timeout.TotalSeconds), allowedUpdates: allowedUpdates);

            Console.WriteLine("Receving " + updates.Length + " updates...");

            foreach (var update in updates!)
            {
                HandleUpdatesAsync(update);

                messageOffset = update.UpdateId + 1;

                Console.WriteLine("MessageId = " + update.UpdateId);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Offsett = " + messageOffset);
        }
    }
```

```
public async Task<Update[]?> GetUpdatesAsync(int offset = 0, int limit = 100, int timeout = 0, string[]? allowedUpdates = default)
{
    var request = new GetUpdatesRequest
    {
        Offset = offset,
        Limit = limit,
        Timeout = timeout,
        AllowedUpdates = allowedUpdates ?? Array.Empty<string>(),
    };

    return await SendRequestAsync<Update[]>(request);
}

private async Task<T?> SendRequestAsync<T>(IRequest request)
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method: request.Method, requestUri: $"{_baseUrl}/{request.MethodName}")
    {
        Content = request.Content
    };

    try
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await s_httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

        var updatesJson = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var response = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Response<T>>(updatesJson, options);

        return response!.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        throw;
    }
}
```

when i run the code and send a message to my bot it keeps printing the "Sending GetUpdate with offsett etc... here's the screenshot of the console

[image]

The only way to stop getting infinite updates is by closing the application or by manualy sending a getUpdate with the SAME offset of the code in the browser like this:

https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates?offset=419787029

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: You never break your loop `while (true)`

Comment: From [the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates): "Must be greater by one than the highest among the identifiers of previously received updates". You're setting it to 1+ the identifier of the *last* update, not 1+ the highest identifier among *all* updates.

Comment: Although, you only get one update, so that probably isn't the cause

Comment: I suspect your `GetUpdatesAsync` isn't adding the offset to the request correctly, but you haven't shared the code for that method

Comment: the last update is tha highest among all btw and GetUpdateAsync only create an GetUpdateRequest. i'll add the code for that method right now.

Comment: Erm, you're putting the offset into the body of your request. It needs to be part of the query string

Comment: @canton7 WOW thank you it finally worked!!!!